# Angular CLI content

Tags: angular

Recently I am trying to work with Angular CLI and as a task I am doing a simple function that when I am clicking a button to show the content.
Till now I am trying it this way:

```
<dm-content>
    <dm-minimal-view>
    Title 
    </dm-minimal-view>

    <dm-default-view>
    Content
    </dm-default-view>

</dm-content>
```

and in my content.component.html I am adding the other code which a saw in a tutorial:

```
<div class="dm-content">
  <ng-content select="dm-minimal-view"></ng-content>
</div>

<div>
    <ng-content select="dm-default-view"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Can anyone help with a hint! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was unclear what you're trying to achieve.
But if you just want to call a function from a button click, use `(click)="yourFunction()"` in your button html.

Comment: i did in this way!
<div (click)="toggleMinimalViewClick()">

<ng-content select="dm-minimal-view"></ng-content>

</div>

<div *ngIf="showDefaultView">
    <ng-content select="dm-default-view"></ng-content>
</div>